# display a panel after just a select Item

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to display a panel after just a select Item, I think of that but it give me an error.

Code:

```
<h:outputText value="* produit" />
<h:selectOneMenu   id="produit" value="#{clientMB.selectProduit}">
        <p:ajax update="client" listener="#{clientMB.getClientsProduit}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" /> 
    <f:selectItems value="#{produitMB.produits}" noSelectionValue="" var="prod" itemValue="#{prod.refProd}" itemLabel="#{prod.libProd}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Autre" itemValue="" value="lazyload()"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:outputPanel id="lazypanel" layout="block">  
        <h:outputText value="This part of page is lazily loaded on demand using a RemoteCommand" rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}"/>  
</p:outputPanel>
```

Error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.faces.model.SelectItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
<h:outputText value="* produit" />
<h:selectOneMenu   id="produit" value="#{clientMB.selectProduit}"  onchange="lazyload()">
<p:ajax update="client" listener="#{clientMB.getClientsProduit}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" /> 
<f:selectItems value="#{produitMB.produits}" noSelectionValue="" var="prod" itemValue="#{prod.refProd}" itemLabel="#{prod.libProd}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Autre" itemValue="" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:outputPanel id="lazypanel" layout="block">  
<h:outputText value="This part of page is lazily loaded on demand using a RemoteCommand" rendered="#{requestScope.shouldRender}"/>  
</p:outputPanel> 
<p:remoteCommand name="lazyload" update="lazypanel">  
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{requestScope.shouldRender}" />  
</p:remoteCommand>
```